# Translation for "N/A" is not used on admin page

Tags: bug, status-review, moderator-tools, localization

Available translation for ["N/A"](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/2245) is not used on [moderator admin page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin?filter=day):

> [image]

It's not really critical, but could please be fixed.

Comment: Yep, looks like this instance of the string isn't currently marked as translatable. (For others' context: this portion of the mod history page shows the number of flags, their average handling time (this line), and the number and percentage of active moderators (i.e., mods who haven't marked themselves as temporarily inactive).)